# Can primary key in one table appear in another table as primary key as well?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I'm sorry for the rather stupid question. 
For example, can one table have composite primary key consisting of **'user_id'** and 'employee_id'

and another table containing **'user_id'** as primary key?

Comment: primary key in one table appear in another table as Foreign key

Comment: If the first table has a composite primary key, that means you can have duplicates of the `user_id` in the table. What's the relationship between `user_id` and `employee_id` in that table, why aren't they each unique?

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: YES, in that case you have one-to-0/1 relationship

For example table `USERS` have PK `user_id`

Then table `SUPERUSERS` have also PK `user_id` and is also `FK` to `users`. Not all users are superusers, and you need define some attributes/roles/privilege to superusers.